# Issue while compiling the Mod_JK 1.2.46

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-jk

I have compiled for the first time `Mod_jk` 1.2.46 version and patched my project files. There are no errors but the following info looks like a possible issue:

```
[info] ajp_process_callback::jk_ajp_common.c (2074): (ajp13) Writing to client aborted or client network problems
[info] ajp_service::jk_ajp_common.c (2775): (ajp13) sending request to tomcat failed (unrecoverable), because of client write error (attempt=1)
[info] jk_handler::mod_jk.c (2984): Aborting connection for worker=ajp13
```

I didn't find any connectivity issue. I'm still not sure this might create any problem later.

Comment: Experts please share your experience on this as soon as possible. - Thanks,Anitha.

Comment: Have you solved your problem? I have a similar issue with Firefox 74+ when submitting file with multipoart. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61547312

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on the server-client communication side, not on your appication. This log tells you that something (a connectivity problem? the client is closed?) block `Mod_jk` when it's trying to send the response generated by Tomcat to the client. Also, make sure that worker.connection_pool_timeout is coherent with the connectionTimeout.